# ReactJS + Router how to access a Redirect's state functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

On the official [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect), it says that to access the state that is passed into the component redirected to, you can use 
`this.props.location.state`

However I'm not using class components and therefore I don't have `this.`.

How do I access the passed state in my redirected component?

Comment: it's passing down through `props`, and you receive `props` as param at your function component like `(props) => (<div>{props.location.state}<div>)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Redirect
    to={{
       pathname: "/signin",
       state: { from: props.location, alert: true },
     }}
 />
```

The following function identifies is there is an alert passed in the state on Redirect. In case `alert:true` it displays the `<div>`

```
let location = useLocation()
function DashboardRedirectAlert() {
    if (location.state?.alert) {
      return <div className="alert alert-warning">Please Signin first</div>;
    } else {
      return <></>;
    }
  }
```

When you try to refer to functional components like the one above, make sure there is something to return always.

Answer (score 0):

In the functional component , there is no this,so you can directly any state by props.''attribution''

Answer (score 0):

You don't allow using `this` in functional component. The true code is:
`Props.location.state`.

In fact `this` keyboard removed because in class components when we want to reach functions and attributes and state use `this` but you use functional component,so not need use this.

Answer (score 0):

It works in functional components well. To access the value in the redirected url
use

```
{( typeof props.location.state != "undefined" ) && props.location.state }
```

You also need to add a check for undefined in case you visit the page without the redirection

Answer (score 0):

In a functional component the `state` prop is available on the `location` object returned from the `useLocation()` hook.

This example uses [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to test if state exists and contains `myVariable`.

```
function LinkToComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: `/myRoute/${props.id}`,
        state: { myVariable: true },
      }}
    >
      Click me
    </Link>
  );
}

function LinkedToComponent(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  // will render only if `myVariable` was passed as `true` in  Link state
  {
    location.state?.myVariable && <p>my variable is true</p>;
  }
}
```